# Wikipedia API. Count error

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I'm using Wikipedia API wrapper to parse data from the page. I'm having a problem with my lexus_count function. That's the output of count function:

```
The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has <function lexus_count at 0x0000020B039A8268> occurrences of the word 'Lexus'"
```

Here is the code:

```
import wikipedia


print ("1: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus vehicles'")
try:
    print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus'))
    print ('-' * 60)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print ('+' * 60)
    print ('DisambiguationError: The page name is ambiguous')
print


print ("2: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus (vehicles)'")
print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)'))
print


result = wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)').content.encode('UTF8')
print ("3: Result of searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus vehicles_(vehicles)':")
print (result)
print


def lexus_count(vehicles):
    lexus_count = result.count(vehicles)
    print


print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
    "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count))
print
```

I have new problem with my count function. Here is error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\College\Python\Labs\lab 3\kaminski_lab3_p2.py in <module>()
     30
     31 print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
---> 32     "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count()))
     33 print

TypeError: lexus_count() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lexus'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lexus_count` is a function. So you have to call it.

```
print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
    "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count()))
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that. Now, I have a new problem here is the error.

Comment: Post in a new question. And please post updated code.